# Cannot correctly mount an encrypted partition from a shell script executed by php

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, mount

I have a very strange behavior running a script supposed to mount an encrypted partition when it's executed by php (5.6). (And Fat-free Framework but that's not a problem)

First, to prevent any permission problem, I've added the following line in `visudo`:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

My shell script is this one:

```
#!/bin/sh


# Verify the command line args number (only one is admitted).
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <passphrase>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# If we run as root, ignore 'sudo' prefix.
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]
then
    SUDO=""
else
    SUDO="sudo"
fi
echo $SUDO
# Get the block device name.
block_dev=$(dmesg | grep 'Attached SCSI' | tail -n1 | tr -d '[]'| awk '{print $4}')
if [ "$block_dev" = "" ]
then
    echo "Unable to find a USB key" >&2
    echo "KO"
    exit 1
fi

# Umount already mounted USB mass storage partition if any.
${SUDO} umount "/dev/${block_dev}"? >/dev/null 2>&1

# Check the block device is really here.
if [ ! -b "/dev/$block_dev" ]
then
    echo "USB key removed." >&2
    echo "KO"
    exit 1
fi

# Check the second partition exists.
if [ ! -b "/dev/${block_dev}2" ]
then
    echo "Invalid USB key partitionning." >&2
    echo "KO"
    exit 1
fi

# Default value for the mapping name if not provided as environment parameter.
MAPPING_NAME="${MAPPING_NAME-cryptoblock}"
echo $MAPPING_NAME
# Umount already mounted mapper if any.
${SUDO} umount "/dev/mapper/$MAPPING_NAME" >/dev/null 2>&1

# Check if the mapper already exists.
if [ -b "/dev/mapper/$MAPPING_NAME" ]
then
    # Remove the crypto loopback.
    ${SUDO} cryptsetup  close  "$MAPPING_NAME"  
fi
echo crypto lock
# Establish the crypto loopback.
printf "$1" | ${SUDO} cryptsetup  --key-file=- --cipher aes-cbc-plain  open  "/dev/${block_dev}2" --type=plain  "$MAPPING_NAME"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Invalid encryption" >&2
    echo "KO"
    exit 1
fi

# Default value for the mount point if not provided as environment parameter.
MOUNT_POINT="${MOUNT_POINT-/mnt/usb}"
echo $MOUNT_POINT
# Mount the second (encrypted) partition.
${SUDO} mount -t vfat /dev/mapper/"$MAPPING_NAME" "${MOUNT_POINT}" -o "rw,nosuid,nodev,shortname=mixed,uid=1000"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    ${SUDO} cryptsetup close "$MAPPING_NAME"
    echo "Invalid passphrase" >&2
    echo "KO"
    exit 1
fi

# Everything seems correct.
sleep 0.5
echo "OK"
exit 0
```

And it perfectly works when I execute it directly from shell. `ls /mnt/usb/` gives me the folder content and I can read files and write to them.

Now I have a php script which contains the following:

```
    $cmd = './mount_usb_lock.sh ' . $this->f3->get('badge.AES') .' 2>&1';
    $ret = exec($cmd, $output);
    $badge = file_get_contents('/mnt/usb/file.lck');
    $this->console_log($badge);
```

And the result is my file's content.

Later, I try to update the file content from php:

```
                $badge = '\rmember_id: '. $member_id;
                file_put_contents('/mnt/usb/file.lck', $badge, FILE_APPEND);
```

And I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error
file_put_contents(/mnt/usb/file.lck): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I also tried to write it from shell script executed by php but the result is the same.

What is strange is that when I execute `ls /mnt/usb` in a shell, I don't see anything like if the partition was not mounted.
But `file_get_contents()` successfully got the file so what's wrong here?
Regards,

Comment: If you're planning on running this on a server accessible from the internet, then `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` in your sudoers file is a super dangerous solution. If someone manages to inject some code somewhere through your site, they can do some real damage.

Comment: @magnus-eriksson thanks for your advice but it's really not my problem at he moment.

Comment: @Dharman, maybe, I can't upgrade.